# Can I create a structure for storing data and send it via MPI?

Tags: c, struct, mpi

I try to parallelize a process that runs an image, and the image takes on a basic operation.
I'm trying to send a structure through MPI defined as follows:

The struct for a pixel:

```
 typedef struct
{       
        unsigned char R;   
        unsigned char G;    
        unsigned char B;    
}pixel;
```

struct for send MPI ( )

```
typedef struct     
{   
    pixel *vec; // pixels for process 3 bytes multiply qty     
    int qty; // count datas     
    int aux; // init      
 } Estructura;
```

I am new to using the MPI library to run in a distributed application, I have used it before but without creating a structure type.
I'm not sure if this is the procedure I should follow.

Could someone explain to me how I could prepare the struct *Estructura* to send?

```
int lens[4]={1,1,1,1};  
MPI_Aint  disps[4];    
MPI_Datatype oldtypes[3], point_type;   
disps[0] = 0; oldtypes[0] = MPI_UNSIGNED;    
disps[1] = &pixel.G - &pixel; oldtypes[1] = MPI_UNSIGNED;    
disps[2] =  &pixel.B - &pixel.G; oldtypes[2] = MPI_UNSIGNED;   
disps[3] = sizeof(pixel); oldtype[3] = MPI_UB;    
MPI_Type_create_struct(3, lens, disps, oldtypes, &point_type);    
MPI_Type_commit(&point_type);
```

**prepare the reception of data**

```
MPI_Status status;                   
MPI_Probe(source, tag, comm, &status);                
MPI_Get_count(&status, point_type, &column.nz);                   
    if (nz == MPI_UNDEFINED)     
MPI_Recv(Estructura.vec, Estructura.qty, Estructura.aux, point_type, source, tag, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);                
pixel *tem =(pixel*)malloc(Estructura.qty *sizeof(point));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems correct. By invoking **MPI_Type_create_struct** you create a custom MPI type. By then invoking **MPI_Type_commit** you can now use the new type. By using the handle created in the MPI_Type_create_struct function. I believe the handle in your code is the variable **point_type**.

So simply invoke `MPI_Send(buffer, count, point_type, dest, tag, comm);`